# Quarriors' Deathdealer and expert culling

Tags: quarriors

When we started using the expert culling rule in Quarriors, we found a confusing interaction with the Deathdealer. It's special ability is:

> When Deathdealer scores, you may trade Deathdealer for one die from any other player's Used Pile.

However, the expert culling rule says that you can only score a creature if you cull that creature's die. How can you swap it and cull it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consensus on BGG is summed up in [this post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/798025/article/9088466#9088466):

> when scoring the death dealer, you would have two "when deathdealer scores" effects that would trigger. 1) cull for points. 2) trade dice.

> If two "when x scores" effects happen at the same time, the active player has to choose which one resolves first. In most cases, this should not be a problem, but for deathdealer the choices are mutually exclusive. If you trade first, you no longer have a dice in your possession to cull. If you cull first, you no longer have a dice in your possession to trade. Thus, you either trade deathdealer or cull it for points.

Answer (score 0):

Our proposal for how to use this creature with the expert culling rule is that when it's in your ready area at the start of your turn, you choose one of the following actions:

1. Score the 2 glory, and cull the Deathdealer die.
2. Trade Deathdealer for one die from any other player's Used Pile.
3. Just move the Deathdealer to your Used Pile.